# Get the hierarchical data but data has not straight forward

Tags: sql-server

We have requirement like to get the hierarchical data but data has not straight forward:
Eg:

```
Level
1
2
3
4
4
5
6
7
7
7
5
5
8
8
9

Here 1 is parent for child 2
         2 is parent for child 3
         3 is parent for children 4,4,4 
        last 4 is parent for child 5
5 is parent for child 6
6 is parent for children 7, 7,7
again 5 is child for last parent 4 
last 7 is parent for child 8
```

Please help me how to write a query to get the above result for the above one

Comment: What have you tried till now? Please read [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post an attempt.

Comment: You would also need to reorganize the data as this does not seem to be good design. Normalization is your friend.

Comment: If you can write output side by side.Is there something else from which we can recognise last 4,last 7 etc.There must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

> How to recognize last 5 or last 7 ?

If you some other info in table which tell this then it is more nice.

Else we can find of our own also but that is little expensive.

Try this,

```
create table #temp( Levels  int)
insert into #temp values
(1),(2),(3),(4)
,(4),(5),(6),(7)
,(7),(7),(5),(5)
,(8),(8),(9)

;With CTE as
(
select * 
,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null))rn
from #temp
)

select * into #temp1
from CTE

;With CTE1 as
(
select * 
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by levels 
order by rn desc)rn1
from #temp1
)

select c.* 
,c1.Levels as Parentid
from CTE1 c
outer apply(select top 1 c1.Levels from CTE1 c1 
where c1.Levels<c.Levels and c1.rn1=1-- last parent 
order by c1.Levels desc)c1
order by c.rn


drop table #temp,#temp1
```

Let me know if it do not work for specific sample data.

Comment: @KalleshiKS,if it help you then Mark it as Answer.